# Magnolia 5.5 Dialogs in Edit-Mode

Tags: magnolia

Since multilanguage is not yet supported by the stories app we are trying to evaluate alternatives

Q1: When will multilanguage be integrated in the stories app?
Q2: I had the idea of rendering components as their dialogs when in edit mode of the pages app. Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: When will multilanguage be integrated in the stories app?

According to the [public Roadmap of Magnolia](https://trello.com/b/TCO4qY0j/magnolia-roadmap) it is one of the next features to be implemented. So roughly in next 3-4 months ... before end of Q1/2018.

> Q2: I had the idea of rendering components as their dialogs when in edit mode of the pages app. Is that possible? How?

You would need to rewrite GWT part of Pages app to render those dialog fields (if what you meant is rendering those fields in the page instead of having green bars for editing).
Alternatively if you just want to have "edit" action that will open dialog showing component source (e.g. when you have component showing "contact" and you want to open contact dialog to edit contact directly), you can just reconfigure edit action (or add another action to the action bar) and have that action open another app. That's rather easy, you just need to construct and issue correct location event. [Here](https://github.com/rah003/neat-tweaks/blob/master/neat-tweaks-developers/src/main/java/com/neatresults/mgnltweaks/ui/action/OpenDefinitionFromPageAction.java) is example of action that would open template definition for selected component from Pages app in the Configuration app.

Comment: Hey Jan, thanks for your answer. Actually I don't want to remove the green bars as for moving components and more they are quite useful. I only want to render the dialog instead of the component preview. And then register a new save-handler to save everything at once. The problem is that we want to edit more than one component at once without hitting save and reloading the page all the time.. Any idea?

Comment: not without some development effort ... you would need to write action that creates dialog combining all the other dialogs. It would get quite long in the end, looking more like endless form and getting editors lost in it, possibly editing wrong parts of such form ... i wouldn't go for it. Other option of just storing edits in memory and applying them all at once later would also be confusing for editors as they wouldn't see their changes. IMO most suitable way is to convert pages for which you want this to stories (or custom content types using content editor) and edit them outside of pages.